# prepareForSegue working on simulator but not on device

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, segue

I am so tired of trying to make this work so i hope somebody here will be able to solve this for me..

I am using this code to segue to a UINavigationController. This code **WORKS** on simulator but **NOT** on a real device:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    static NSString *segueIdentifier = @"ShowDetails";

    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:segueIdentifier]) {

        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];

        UINavigationController *navigationController = segue.destinationViewController;
        DetailViewController *detailViewController = [navigationController viewControllers][0];


        detailViewController.selectedGameIdNumber = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%ld", (long)indexPath.row];
        detailViewController.selectedSection = [self.sectionNames objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    }
}
```

On the real device it crashes at:

```
 DetailViewController *detailViewController = [navigationController viewControllers][0];
```

with the error:

```
-[DetailViewController viewControllers]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

Then i have this code that i tried. This code **WORKS** on device but **NOT** on simulator:

```
  -(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    static NSString *segueIdentifier = @"ShowDetails";

    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:segueIdentifier]) {

        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];

        DetailViewController * detailViewController = (DetailViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;


        detailViewController.selectedGameIdNumber = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%ld", (long)indexPath.row];
        detailViewController.selectedSection = [self.sectionNames objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    }
}
```

On the simulator it crashes at:

```
detailViewController.selectedGameIdNumber = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%ld", (long)indexPath.row];
```

With the error:

```
 -[UINavigationController setSelectedGameIdNumber:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fa1d273e8
```

Am i doing something wrong or should i just run with the second code that works on real device?
I want to have a clean solution so please do enlighten me if i am doing something wrong. Thank you all.

Comment: Which simulator/iOS version, and which device/iOS version?  I suspect the answer is that you will have to code defensively for both situations (i.e. test the class of the destination view controller with `isKindOfClass:` and handle each case accordingly).

Comment: Deployment target is set to 7.1 for the simulator and my device is running on IOS 7.1.1 iPhone 5s @pbasdf

Comment: Is the simulator running 7.1 as well? (the deployment target is something different)  Which device is being simulated?

Comment: It says IOS SDK 8.1 in the project file name @pbasdf

Comment: I suspected it might be iOS8 - Apple changed the way segues work in iOS8.  As I suggested before, to accommodate both cases, check the class of the segue's `destinationViewController` - if it is `[UINavigationController class]`, then use your 1st block of code above, if it is `[DetailViewController class]` then use your 2nd block of code.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with how you are accessing the view controller. On the device the view controller hierarchy is different from on the simulator, and so the two solutions both only work in their own scenario. Of course it isn't the simulator that is different, but rather the device you are simulating (guess is iPad)

Be aware that, especially with splitViewcontrollers, but also with other framework provided view controllers that the functionality of the controllers may vary based on the target device. This change often bites you when you make assumptions about indexes of view controllers and the like.

Debug on the simulator, switching between device types and po the view controller and I think you will see what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution: creating a generic struct and cast the customized viewcontroller by function call. The advantage is that you can reuse this function everywhere you need it.
(Though my code is in written in swift rather than Objective-C, I think the way of solution is just alike)

```
struct DestinationController<T: UIViewController> {
    func get(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) -> T {
        if let navigation = segue.destinationViewController as? UINavigationController{
            return navigation.viewControllers.first as! T
        }
        return segue.destinationViewController as! T
    }
}
```